# Extracting the degrees of freedom of t distribution of a GAM

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I would have a rather easy question regarding the output when fitting a GAM using the mgvz package and assuming t distributed data.

Sample code is taken from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/scat.html

```
library(mgcv)
## Simulate some t data...
set.seed(3);n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
dat$y <- dat$f + rt(n,df=4)*2

b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=scat(link="identity"),data=dat)
```

summary(b) yields the output “Family: Scaled t(5.376,2.088)”.

My question is whether I am right assuming that:

•   5.376 = degrees of freedom of the t distribution (nu)

•   2.088 = sigma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the actual values directly, {mgcv} has this hidden functionality of an extractor function buried in the `family` object of the fitted model. If the model has some additional parameters like the scaled *t* or negative binomial (`nb()`) families, there will be a function `getTheta` in the `family`.

These are not typically well documented in the {mgcv} help, unfortunately. Usually what is returned by `getTheta()` will be on the scales used for actual model fitting. To get them back on a more useful scale (like the $\nu$ and $\sigma$ parameters displayed in the output from `summary()`) `getTheta()` typically has a `trans` argument:

```r
f <- family(b)
args(f$getTheta)
f$getTheta()
f$getTheta(trans = TRUE)
```

which produces:

```
> f <- family(b)
> args(f$getTheta)
function (trans = FALSE) 
NULL
> f$getTheta()
[1] 0.8653386 0.7362529
> f$getTheta(trans = TRUE)
[1] 5.375810 2.088097
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! :) I have read a couple of posts regarding GAMs and your answers were always very helpful!

Comment: Definitely agree. Noam Ross and Gavin Simpson are excellent at communicating how GAMs work.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is a bit confusing, but the first is nu and the second is sigma as is explained in the docs for the argument `theta`

> the parameters to be estimated nu = b + exp(theta_1) (where ‘b’ is min.df) and sig = exp(theta_2). If supplied and both positive, then taken to be fixed values of nu and sig. If any negative, then absolute values taken as starting values.

you can check this by providing those values yourself

```
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),
        family=scat(theta=c(10, 2), link="identity"),
        data=dat)
summary(b)
```

which now outputs `Family: Scaled t(10,2)`

**edit:** See also Simpson's answer bellow