# Simulating from fitted t-distribution mgcv

Tags: mgcv, t-distribution

My question is related to the following post:

[Extracting the degrees of freedom of t distribution of a GAM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550339/extracting-the-degrees-of-freedom-of-t-distribution-of-a-gam)

I have a dataset of y-values that I am fitting using the gam-function in mgcv. The distribution of y is shown below.

[image]

The tailed nature of the data has led me to use scaled t-distribution with a log-link function. The summary of the fit outputs the following result for the fitted t-distribution:

Family: Scaled t(3.615,2476.626)
Link function: log

How would I go about plotting the above scaled t-distribution on top of the density plot above. I am unsure about the significance of the values and how the relate to the degrees of freedom and mean of the distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *t* distribution doesn't look like a good fit for your data. The scaled *t* distribution has support on the entire real number line, from -infinity to plus infinity, while your data seems to be strictly positive.

If you have 0s in your data, I would try the Tweedie family, `tw()`. If not, the gamma family with log link would also be a good starting point, `Gamma(link = "log")`.

Also, we don't expect the response to be distributed *t*, or Tweedie, or Gamma, *as a whole* when we are modelling with GLMs or GAMs. When you specify the `family`, what you are saying is that you expect each observation to be a draw from that distribution, with it's own mean $\mu_i$. That mean is determined by the model. It would be entirely wrong to plot a single *t* (or other) distribution on top of the density plot of the observed response.

What you can do instead is simulate a new data set as large as the observed one, and plot its density along side the density of the response. Usually one might plot the densities of several simulate data (20-100) and look to see if the observations simulated from the model you fitted are a close facsimile of the observed data. If your model is able to recreate features of your observed data then it is one indication that it is well fitted.